# RaspberryPi - calling your iPhone from your RaspberryPi

Tags: sip, voip, pbx

I'm new to using a RaspberryPi but I've seen a large amount of videos which show a Raspberry Pi calling the user's iPhone. I'm interested and I've tried look up tutorials but due to the fact that everything is new to me/my lack of knowledge, I'm getting nowhere.

I was wondering if anyone could give me a hand in understanding what's meant by the different VoIP, PBX, SIP client etc termonology and how I can set it up myself.

Comment: It would be useful to show what you've tried / looked at so far.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've only watched a couple videos about asterix, uelastix and free PBXs.

Answer (score 2):

What you will need to accomplish this are:

- A SIP server (also called as Softswitch or PBX). For example [Asterisk for Linux](http://www.asterisk.org/) or [VoIP server for windows](https://www.mizu-voip.com/Software/VoIPServer.aspx)
- SIP clients (also called as [Softphone](http://www.voipsupply.com/blog/voip-insider/free-sip-softphone-roundup/)) for your Raspberry Pi (for example a java softphone or a linux client) and for iPhone (Zoiper, Bria, MizuPhone, 3CX, others)

Once your server is running, just create 2 accounts (username/password) and in the softphones enter your server address (IP or domain) and username/password. Then you will be able to call from one client to another by dialing the username.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:  purchase VOIP service from a VOIP provider like PhonePower, or any other one that will provide SIP credentials.  Yeah, there are free ones, like Google Voice, but sometimes you get what you pay for.

Your VOIP provider will provide SIP credentials, which you put into your soft phone application (like Zoiper or whatever).

Now your Pi can call your cell phone or indeed any other phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/?pdv=c&pcrid=%7Bcreative%7D&pmt=e&pkw=twilio&campaign=Bing_Search_Brand_Alpha_NA&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=twilio&utm_campaign=Bing_Search_Brand_Alpha_NA&utm_content=Brand&msclkid=8be66521927718f0355b39cccadee53a&gclid=CKaplvPJvuICFUMEGwod-yEA_g&gclsrc=ds) it can make phone calls in python.